# invertibility of the block Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Consider a block Vandermonde square matrix

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{\Omega}(i_0) & \mathbf{\Omega}(2i_0) & \ldots & \mathbf{\Omega}((2p-1)i_0) \\
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{\Omega}(-i_0) & \mathbf{\Omega}(-2i_0) & \ldots & \mathbf{\Omega}(-(2p-1)i_0) \\
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{\Omega}(i_1) & \mathbf{\Omega}(2i_1) & \ldots & \mathbf{\Omega}((2p-1)i_1) \\
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{\Omega}(-i_1) & \mathbf{\Omega}(-2i_1) & \ldots & \mathbf{\Omega}(-(2p-1)i_1) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{\Omega}(i_{p-1}) & \mathbf{\Omega}(2i_{p-1}) & \ldots & \mathbf{\Omega}((2p-1)i_{p-1}) \\
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{\Omega}(-i_{p-1}) & \mathbf{\Omega}(-2i_{p-1}) & \ldots & \mathbf{\Omega}(-(2p-1)i_{p-1}) 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{4p \times 4p}$$
where 
$$\mathbf{\Omega}(i) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(2\pi i /M) &-\sin(2\pi i/M) \\ 
\sin(2\pi i /M) &\cos(2\pi i /M) 
\end{bmatrix}$$
which is a rotation matrix, $0<i_0 < i_1 < \ldots < i_{p-1} <M$

Note that all the entry is $2 \times 2$.

### Question

#### How to show $X$ is invertible?

Comment: I suspect there are some row/column operations that turn $X$ into a complex Vandermonde matrix (as opposed to a real block-Vandermonde matrix) which is then easily shown to be invertible.